# JavaScript: Convert String as Parameter to Array Name?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to convert Function Parameter string to Array name?

```
function SwitchElement(type){

    var cur = type.indexOf(document.getElementById(type).src);
    console.log(cur);
    if(cur < eyes.length-1){

    }
}
```

So that "type" is Addressed as array name.

If so, how? I am trying to do it just like that function but it returns me index -1

Note: Div of element and Arrayname share same name.

Comment: what do you mean by 'array name'?

Comment: I have few arrays.
For example: eyes, clothes, hair.
I want to specify "type" variable as one of those 3.

Comment: you should just pass it in.

Comment: Passing an array to `getElementById` would not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are passing in a string, the best way to handle this would be to arrange your arrays into an object. So instead of:

```
var skins = [];
var eyes = [];
// etc...
```

You'll have something like:

```
parts = {
    skins: [],
    eyes: [],
    // etc
};
```

Now in your function you can do something like:

```
function SwitchElement(type){

    var cur = parts[type].indexOf(document.getElementById(type).src);
    console.log(cur);
    if(cur < parts[type].length-1){

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that should be `parts[type].indexOf(...)`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yep. Completely missed they had that there.

Comment: So without arranging arrays into object it's not possible to easily convert string to array name which exists already?

I have 7 arrays which share same function but accessing different array, I would love if I can re-use that function by just specifying which array to use in parameters.

Comment: @arleitiss: You can, by putting them in an object. And as a bonus you don't have 7 arrays polluting the global namespace, instead you have just one object. Technically, you could use `eval`, but don't. It's terrible practice.

Comment: @MattBurland I found another answer on stackoverflow last night, it suggested just writing: this[arrayname/paramter] and that works as reference to array I want (basically what I want to get done), not using eval